# Create a table of contents with hyperlinks in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

Is there a way to create a table of contents in Google Docs like you would in a wiki?

I have huge documents with many sections. I currently use block quotes to separate those sections and keep things in perspective.

However, it would be nice to have some tag that I can give to titles and then those tags appear as a table of contents at the top. That way I can easily browse though different things.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can create a table of Contents in Google Docs;

1. Add headings to your document by clicking **Format > Paragraph styles** in the toolbar, and selecting a heading.
2. Click **Table of contents** from the **Insert** menu. The table of contents appears wherever you've clicked in the document, so make sure you place your cursor where you want to add the table of contents. If you need to move the table of contents, select it as you would select text and either move it with your cursor or cut it and paste it.
3. You can continue to add headings to your document or change current headings. However, if you'd like a change to become part of the table of contents, you need to click first the table and then the **Update now** button.
4. Each item in your table of contents links to the titled sections of your document that use the heading styles (that you added in step 1 above).

Related help article: [Add a title, heading, or table of contents in a document](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=106342)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to link any text in your google doc, provided you've set up a table of contents linked to your headings, is to highlight the text(s) of interest, right click and select "Link", scroll down to headings and click on it to display all headings and select the heading you would like the highlighted text to link to and click apply.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a Table of Contents as suggested in the [accepted answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/16439/) is a great approach but you can also create **Bookmarks** linking to any part of the document or copy the link to an existing **heading**.

### Create Bookmarks

Source: [Work with links & bookmarks](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/45893)

1. Click where you want the bookmark.
2. Click **Insert** and then **Bookmark**

### Use Existing Heading Links

To link directly to headings without creating a Table of Contents:

1. Click on the heading
2. Copy the URL from your browser's address bar which will now also include the heading after the hash `#` mark.

For example, if your document URL when you opened it was

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YcBrKx71jkvVl3muIRSh/edit
```

Once you click on the heading it would be something similar to:

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YcBrKx71jkvVl3muIRSh/edit#heading=h.2at2fr1a8bsb
```

That URL can be used wherever needed.

Comment: This might not have been available at the time of the original answer, but when inserting a link (via `CTRL+K` et al) there is an option below the textbox to choose from document headings -- it accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You CAN use the **Outline** at the left side of the Document page as an Index it's a little Tab with a sort of Tablet icon below the Toolbar, if you don't see it go to **View** then select **Show document outline** and you'll see it show up on the left.

All you do is change each header to a Title. Highlight each one, then in the Toolbar click where it says **Normal Text** to open the Drop Down Menu, move your mouse over **Title** and click Apply 'Title' then just change the Font and Size back to what you had it set as.

The only thing is the Normal Text can't be in the same line as the Title so you'll have to start your Normal Text under it.