# Add relative link to header in Google Document using URL fragment

Tags: google-docs

I already know how to add links via Bookmarks and Table of Contents.  I also know how to [directly link to a header](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/30318/23626)

However, rather than pasting the entire URL for the header, which creates an absolute link to that specific Google Doc, I want to just paste the fragment (`#header=h.abc123xyz`).  This has the benefit of being *document relative*, in the sense that if someone makes a copy of my document, saves it as an HTML page, etc. (thus changing the URL), the anchor will still work as expected in the new document.  Currently, it would just link to the section of the *original* document.

Is this possible?

*Note*: I've tried just pasting the fragment in the regular *Insert Link* dialog, but Google thinks it's an invalid URL.  Is there a workaround?  Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I click `Insert` / `Link...` and put in `#header=h.abc123xyz`, when I save it as an HTML document it is converted to `#h.abc123xyz` and it works as expected.

Comment: Yes, since I asked the question they apparently allowed this behavior.  In fact, when you now choose "Insert Link" (`CTRL+K`) it gives you a dropdown to select section headers, which then inserts the `#heading...` thing.