# Create table of contents in Google Docs from only specific heading types

Tags: google-docs

If I have a Google Docs document with various heading values, can I create table of contents from only specific heading values?

The reason I'd like to do this is to create a to-do list that updates when I tag certain sentences as a heading value. I'd like to create an n number of lists that link to other parts of the document dynamically.

```
INSERT TABLE OF CONTENTS

(only grab from Heading 2)
• Dog
• Man 

(only grab from Heading 1)
• cat


DOCUMENT
Cat <- Heading 1

Dog <- Heading 2

Man <- Heading 2

Wom <- Heading 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such support in Google Docs. However, there are a few options to get around this:

1. You can keep the Headings you want to be shown in the Table of Contents as Heading 1 and manually format the other headings.

   > INSERT TABLE OF CONTENTS
   >
   > (only grab from Heading 2)
   >   • Dog
   >   • Man
   >
   > DOCUMENT
   >   Cat -> Heading 1
   >   Dog -> Heading 2
   >   Man -> Heading 2
   >   Wom -> Manually format this to Heading 3 (Change the font size, etc.)
2. You can keep your heading structure and write out the table of contents on your own and create hyperlinks to these headings listed in your table of contents. (Here is a link on how to create hyperlinks: [Create a table of contents with hyperlinks in Google Docs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16429/create-a-table-of-contents-with-hyperlinks-in-google-docs))

Hope that helps!