# How can I configure the maximum heading number to display in the table of contents sidebar in Google document?

Tags: google-docs

How can I configure the maximum heading number to display in the table of contents sidebar in Google document?

By default any text that is a header is displayed in the sidebar:

[image]

I would prefer to have just the headers 1 and 2 there.

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/65928/create-table-of-contents-in-google-docs-from-only-specific-heading-types

Comment: @Rubén thanks I'll keep an eye on it as well.