# How do I share a permalink from Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, links

Now that Google Docs has transitioned into Google Drive, how do I share a permalink?

I understand that I can "Share" a document, and send an email notification as well. But I'm trying to keep all communications in a single thread, therefore the need for a permalink.

Where is the permalink for a Google Drive document?

Comment: Similarly, how can you use Google Drive to share a ZIP file download? Sharing a link to a ZIP you've uploaded seems to point to a page that let's you browse the contents of that ZIP, rather than download the whole thing.

Comment: @JoostSchuur I just posted your question, I need to figure this out as well http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30654/in-google-drive-how-can-you-link-directly-to-download-a-zip-file-and-not-view

Answer (score 13):

**The easiest method I've found is to simply open the document and copy the URL in your browser's address bar**. That URL **is** a permalink to the files on your account. This is a good method because you can share the link but only the people you have shared the document with will be allowed to view the file (anyone not on the list will get an access denied message).

**The other method is to enable public sharing:**

1. Open the document and click the ***Share*** button,
2. Click ***Change*** next to the privacy settings at the top
3. Select ***Anyone with the Link***, Click Save

You will now see a Permalink to your document. *Note that this is **public** for, well... anyone with the link!*

*[(you can also link to specific parts within the document using bookmarks)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/1799/16428)*

Answer (score 3):

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID
```

Replace the `FILE_ID` with your file id. If you don't know were the file ID is, then check [this article](http://www.bloggerpanda.com/2014/01/how-to-make-direct-download-links-in.html).

Comment: Article link broken...

Answer (score 1):

You can use **gdriveurl.com**, it got updated and now allows users to log in with their Google Drive account and share the list of files instantly, getting for each file "**View**" & "**Download**" short permalink.

There's also the old solution (login to Google Drive, set everything to "Public on web", copy share link, convert it into the gdriveurl.com textarea in the homepage), but it's just a waste of time, you should try MyDrive API.

Answer (score -1):

You will find the answer also in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11466763/1510584)

It suggests you [this website](http://www.gdriveurl.com) that generates a static link for your Drive uploads and everyone will be able to see it (you can try with an other browser where you aren't logged in with Google account).

Answer (score -1):

To save links, use Google Bookmarks. Simply add your link. This is great for me because I use multiple devices.

Answer (score -2):

It is a simple hack I hope it will help.

```
 1. open your drive and change privacy settings of the file to public.      
 2. Then try to download it.
 3. Then copy the download link add it to where you want to make link.
```