# Google Drive permalink that doesn't change with new file versions

Tags: links, google-drive, version-control

I have a file that I'm storing on Google Drive and I update it frequently with new versions (multiple times a day, sometimes). So far, when I copy the link from the "Share" window that allows other people to see the file, that link ceases to work after I upload a new version. Is there a way to make a link that links to whatever the current version of a particular file is?

Answer (score 12):

If you want to be able to use the same share link you need to upload your new file as a new revision not a new file.  Every time you upload a new file it will generate a new share link.  However, if you upload a revision it will keep the same share link every time.

To upload a new version of a file using the web interface:

1. Log into your drive and find the file or folder you wish to revise.
2. Tick the checkbox next to the file or folder.
3. From the dropdown that comes from the More button, click on **Manage Revisions**.
    a. If you are viewing a file it will be under the **File** menu.
4. A dialog box will appear in the top part of the box click the link "**Upload a new revision**"

Old revisions are kept per Google for 30 days or 100 revisions whichever comes first.  Ofcourse from this same option you can delete or save revisions yourself.

---

Samples:

[image: Google Drive Manage Revisions Sample Menu Navigation]
[image: Google Drive Manage Revisions Sample Dialog Box]

Comment: I noticed, when I walked through these instructions, that it only works if you don't convert to the Google version of the file.

Comment: You can't find this feature in the new Google Drive

Comment: Checked in the current version on Drive as suggested by Ooker.  The process is still the same process with two exceptions.  First you now can right click on the file, and the renamed the menu item to **Manage Versions**.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [gdriveurl.com](http://gdriveurl.com)

It takes the ID of file and process it once, giving you a permalink of the resource. When you update the file and try to reach the file with the same link, it will give you as result the same file as the ID is permanent.

[Here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/53712/55910) you can find more details about my answer.

Comment: If you are affiliated with the product, please disclose that in the answer.

Comment: service seems to be down

Answer (score 1):

It all depends if you uploaded the *original* file using Google Sheets or Docs. Then the above **does not work**. The above only pertains to Original uploads to Google Drive.
If you uploaded the *original* using Google Sheets or Docs, do the following instead:

1. Open the original file in either "Google Sheets" or "Google Docs"
2. Select "File" on your "Sheets" or "Doc" Menu
3. In the dropdown menu select "Import"
4. On menu bar that appears select "Upload"
5. Browse and select your new revised file to replace the original Google Sheet or Doc
6. After upload is complete a dialog box will appear with a highlighted "Import Data" button on left bottom corner, and a drop down tab with arrow in center left of the dialog box
7. Click the arrow in drop down tab
8. Select "Replace Spreadsheet" or "Doc"
9. Answer the question  "Yes"
10. You are done. Your new uploaded file will not replace your existing "Sheet" or "Doc" with the same link.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent suggestion by Bradley.
I also suggest to uncheck the "do not auto delete" flag, for all the versions, unless you have specific requirements.
In this way you:

- won't be accounted on your Drive space consumption for the space required for older versions;
- you will have older versions automatically deleted after 30 days (or after 100 versions are loaded).

I would also like to answer to Sonya: if you want a newer version of a "native" Google doc, simply cut and paste the new content, overlying the old content.
Google Docs manages automatically versions, and you can additionally check the specific parts that were added or edited by each collaborative user.