# If I replace a PDF file in Google Drive, will the share link stay the same, or will I have to give out a new one?

Tags: pdf, google-drive

If I replace a PDF file in Google Drive, by dragging a new one into the folder on my hard drive and ok-ing the replace operation when Windows asks, will the share link stay the same, or will I have to give out a new one?

Comment: I don't want to just test this because it's actively linked to from somewhere on the web and I don't want to break that. I don't understand what it is about this question that warrants downvoting, either.

Comment: I don't know why this was migrated. It's not clearly about the web interface of Google Drive. You can get a "share" link directly from the PC app.

Answer (score 3):

Uploading a new file with the same name isn't considered the same file. This means the share link will change. If you want to avoid this, use the 'Manage revisions' feature as explained in this post: [Google Drive permalink that doesn't change with new file versions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30512/google-drive-permalink-that-doesnt-change-with-new-file-versions)