# In Google Drive, how can you link directly to "Download" a zip file and not view the contents?

Tags: google-drive

When you share a Zip file in Google Drive, you land on a page to view all the files inside the zip file and to download the entire file the user has to click *File → Download*. I've noticed a lot of users don't get this so I actually have to tell them to click *File → Download* when all I really want to do is give them a link to directly download the file.

Comment: I found out that for some reason, the direct link works only on the current file version. If I update the zip files and upload it again to Google Drive, with the same name, the direct link I have created before goes to the old version of the file and not the new file. So I have to create a new direct link, which doesn't help so much.

Comment: @user39655 - I have minimal experience with Google Drive so I don't know if it would work, but couldn't you share a folder, then whatever files and file-versions you put into the folder would be shared.

Comment: Same post, just in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25010369/435605

Answer (score 62, accepted):

For the moment, you have to build the URL manually.

```
https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=YourIndividualID
```

Where `YourIndividualID` is the ID of the respective document (zip file). You get it either from the URL or by clicking *File → Share* and copying it from the sharing URL.

[Source](http://thebiobucket.blogspot.it/2011/10/how-to-link-to-google-docs-for-download.html).

Comment: I do this quite a bit so created a Google sheet that I can paste the original sharing link into so it can pull out the ID then creates the new direct download link.

Comment: is there any file size limit? for some reason I can't seem to download a 2.1GB `.zip` file using this method and `wget`, but I can download e.g. a smaller `.zip` file. It also doesn't detect the filetype.

Comment: it was because of the virus scanner of gdrive. I currently have not found a solution (but I did realize I could simply `scp` the files since I could connect through `ssh` to the machine I wanted to download to).
Looks like it may not be possible at all? see http://stackoverflow.com/a/38711808/5272567

Comment: It's kind of hack way,  i worry it will not work in future. Is there any official way to do that

Comment: Not working....

Comment: This works for files. Is there a solution for a directory?

Comment: The article [Share Direct Links to Files in Google Drive and Skip the Web Viewer](https://lifehacker.com/share-direct-links-to-files-in-google-drive-and-skip-th-1493813665) shares a bit more information about how to construct the URL correctly.

Comment: I just spent an hour on chat with Google "support" about this problem (users seeing a Web page showing the contents of a zip file instead of being prompted to download). It took the full hour to get the brain-dead rep to even grasp the problem, after which she merely repeated it over and over. File feedback on this BS.

Answer (score 11):

Also, while viewing the content of zip file, you can click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to download the whole directory as zip file.

Comment: How does one "view the contents of a zip file" in Google Drive? I think you meant to say "view the contents of a folder".

Comment: Unfortunately, sending someone a link to a zip file (using Google's "get shareable link") results in them seeing the contents of the zip file instead of being prompted to download it. That's the entire topic of this post.

Answer (score 8):

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=YOUR_FILE_ID
```

Replace "YOUR_FILE_ID" for the ID of your file

Answer (score 2):

This is also a good link:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=XXXXXXXXX
```

with antivirus inactive, and you can download files of any size.

Just replace the xxxxx by the file ID that you get when sharing a file:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=0BzAzYuV51kTzRkt4bEpIZ3UwX3c
```

Comment: confirm=no_antivirus doesn't stop the warning/prompt for scanning

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a user script for this you can install with Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey:
https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/10052-google-drive-direct-links