# Is there a direct download links for files on Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Google Drive, how can you link directly to “Download” a zip file and not view the contents?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30654/in-google-drive-how-can-you-link-directly-to-download-a-zip-file-and-not-view)

I want to store several files on Google Drive that later will need to be downloaded without authorization by some automated tool (for example filters for adblock so several different PCs can update from them). Is it possible to generate direct download link for file on Google Drive that would work without authorization?

Answer (score 31):

If you want to link to a file at Google Docs for direct download you can use the following address scheme: https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=YourIndividualID

More information [here](http://thebiobucket.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-link-to-google-docs-for-download.html).

Comment: Yeah it works great! Obviously you have to mark it as public.

Comment: Also works with drive domain name: `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=YourFileID`

Comment: If you want, I’ve just launched a small chrome extension to get this link directly from Google drive interface. Feel free to have a look:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/drive-direct-download/mpfdlhhpbhgghplbambikplcfpbjiail

Comment: @AlexisClarembeau is this open source?  if so, can you provide the repo location?  I'd feel more comfortable installing it if I could see the code.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, I am getting a 404.

Answer (score 5):

You can actually set view/edit permissions to any e-mail address by clicking the `Share`-button in the upper right but the persons who gets the permissions will have to create a new Google account or sign in with an existing Google account use the document.

Alternatively, you can set the document to be viewed and edited by anyone who has the link to the document (no sign-in required), email the link to the particular email address and request them to not share the link with anyone else.

You can see the screenshots below:

[image]

Then, Click on the "Change" button:

[image]

Now, select the setting as shown in this screen shot and click on "Save":

[image]

Now, Copy the links as shown in the screen shot below and share it with anyone you want through email. Do not forget to click on the "Done" button:

[image]

Comment: Tried that, exatly that.  Simply does not work.  `curl` downloads some html, w3m just shows a link to some login.  No file.

Comment: does not work tried doing a wget on sharable link ... fails