# How can I hotlink an mp3 in Google Drive with a URL ending in .mp3?

Tags: google-drive, file-sharing, mp3

I would like to obtain a link to an mp3 hosted in Google Drive that has the format `filename.mp3`, so I can link to it from sites that provide in-line audio players when linking to mp3 files.

I have searched the web and different SE sites, but the closest thing to a solution I have found is [obtaining a direct download link for the file](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33997/is-there-a-direct-download-links-for-files-on-google-drive) or advice on hosting it elsewhere. However, for (future) convenience I would prefer to host and link directly from / to Google Drive.

Can anyone provide some insight or point out why this might not work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT: This answer is outdated. googledrive.com/host has been deprecated as of August 31st 2016 and no longer works.**

Yes, it is possible.

1. First, change the directory permission to public in which your mp3 files reside.
2. Copy the folder ID, that will be at the end of URL when you are inside the directory. It will be something like this

   ```
    0C2QKl-TsV6cVTE7wbWNOelRiRlk
   ```
3. Next you can access the mp3 files using hosted mode:

   ```
    https://googledrive.com/host/0C2QKl-TsV6cVTE7wbWNOelRiRlk/filename.mp3
   ```

Note that the beginning part of the URL changes to `https://googledrive.com/host/` for hosted mode compared to "normal" shared link mode URL `https://drive.google.com/open?id=`.

Comment: Thank you, Baljeet! This comes very close to what I had in mind. Do you know whether there is any way in which this procedure can be altered so the directory permission does not need to be set to "Public", but can instead be set to "Anyone with the link" while maintaining full functionality?

Comment: @nholtappels I think currently this is the only way

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this works anymore. I made my folder public but this is the url i get `https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0GRVvnH21RdT3MwQ3lzN3Vjdnc&authuser=0` and my filename inside it is **intro.wav**

Comment: It does work. @JGallardo you must use the googldrive.com/host url instead of the url it gives you when you click share

Comment: This answer is outdated. googledrive.com/host has been deprecated as of August 31st 2016 and no longer works.

Answer (score 14):

If you share an MP3 by link, you obtain a link like this

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/view?usp=sharing
```

where `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` is the **ID** of your MP3 file.
Then you can obtain a direct link to this audio by

```
http://docs.google.com/uc?export=open&id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

In particular you can use

```
<audio controls>
   <source src="http://docs.google.com/uc?export=open&id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" type="audio/mp3">
   <p>Your browser does not support HTML5 audio :(</p>
</audio>
```

Comment: The URL starting with https://googledrive.com/host/... in the accepted answer no longer works. This should now be the correct answer.

Comment: The accepted  answer   googledrive.com/host...  should be downvoted until removed (people waste their time trying)

Comment: for people coming after 2023, this answer worked for me

Answer (score 9):

Don't know if this still helps anybody, but this can be done. With an “anybody with the link can view the file” link:

- prefix the file ID with `uc?id=` and append it with `&export=download`

So it would look like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/uc?id=FILE-ID&export=download
```

Comment: Thank's, this should be the accepted answer! If you want your .mp3 to start playing immediately in the browser use `&export=open`.

Answer (score 3):

This example works:

```
<audio controls="">
   <source src="http://docs.google.com/uc?export=open&amp;id=1uZd99P8_xWM3fYsoSl4xHa8md2MWHa68" type="audio/mp3"></source>
   Your browser does not support HTML5 audio <br />

</audio>
```

Comment: +1 for being the first user to post this method (Kpym is the second one), but please add explanations so others can understand **why** are they doing something, i.e. why something works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

spent an entire day on this problem. like others say it
`https://docs.google.com/uc?export=open&id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`
worked few minutes then it got blocked.

I used Github.  basically, you can drag and drop an MP4 file to an issue then use that link to upload in my code works.   NOT MP3 because GitHub allows only certain files to be uploaded.  then I googled mp3 convert to mp4   (which https://www.zamzar.com/). works.

Answer (score 0):

I researched this topic today for about an hour. As of recently (i.e. 2015/05), I also don't believe it's possible any more, but I'd love to be proved wrong.

### References

- https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/gyv_QYx8T7M
- https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/drive/8dTBhovs38U/9pvfxjQxgnkJ

Comment: I edited the answer on 5/26/2016. I did not know that there is a hosted mode for Google Drive. Note that the beginning part of the URL changes to `https://googledrive.com/host/` for hosted mode compared to "normal" shared link mode URL `https://drive.google.com/open?id=`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and got it work with the following URL:

```
https://docs.google.com/uc?export=open&id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Great. I was able to get some luck with the following structure: 

`"https://drive.google.com/uc?id=XXXX&authuser=0&export=download"`

Comment: This was mentioned in a [previous answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/84399/88163)