# Google Drive direct download for big files

Tags: google-drive

I am trying [In Google Drive, how can you link directly to "Download" a zip file and not view the contents?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30654/in-google-drive-how-can-you-link-directly-to-download-a-zip-file-and-not-view) but it does not work. I am not sure on how to repeat the question. It downloads a 'file is too big to be antivirus scanned' warning HTML and when I try `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=` it still downloads that.

Edit: I tried to `wget --save-cookies /tmp/cookie.txt --load-cookies /tmp/cookie.txt` and repeat it, still no dice.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Running into the same problem with bigger files.

Comment: No, I gave up on this.

Comment: **Very similar question** from Stack Overflow, with good answers: "[wget/curl large file from google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25010369)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A cookie must match the "confirm" url parameter, and it is changed on each call.

[Here's a perl script to download these files](https://github.com/circulosmeos/gdown.pl) in an unattended way.

With the url from the antivirus scan warning page (*https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=s5vl&id=XXX*) this code should be enough:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my $TEMP='/tmp';my $COMMAND;my $confirm;
sub execute_command();
my $URL=shift;my $FILENAME=shift;
$FILENAME='gdown' if $FILENAME eq '';
execute_command();
if (-s $FILENAME < 100000) { # only if file isn't the download yet
    open fFILENAME, '<', $FILENAME;
    foreach (<fFILENAME>) {
        if (/confirm=([^;&]+)/) {
            $confirm=$1; last;   }    }
    close fFILENAME;
    $URL=~s/confirm=([^;&]+)/confirm=$confirm/;
    execute_command();    }
sub execute_command() {
    $COMMAND="wget --no-check-certificate --load-cookie $TEMP/cookie.txt --save-cookie $TEMP/cookie.txt \"$URL\"";
    $COMMAND.=" -O \"$FILENAME\"" if $FILENAME ne '';
    `$COMMAND`; return 1;    }
```

Comment: I've made a python script, and my cookie matches the confirm parameter in the url. However, it does not work: I am being redirected to a page titled "Sign in - Google Accounts".

Comment: Benjamin: you may need to process the url twice... look how the script calls execute_command() twice.

Comment: You can get the URL argument necessary for this script by doing: 1. Copy the Google Drive file link from the "Share" dialog (right-click on the file, then "Share"); 2. Go to [Google Drive Direct Link Generator](https://sites.google.com/site/gdocs2direct/), paste the link in the text box, and click on "Create Direct Link"; 3. Copy the generated link and browse it; 4. Copy the link associated with the blue button with the label "Download anyway", and use it with this script.

Answer (score 9):

After spending many countless hours trying to get a direct download link that bypasses the virus scan I finally figured it out by accident. A URL in the format below along with your Google API key will bypass the virus scan. I could not find this documented anywhere ([here is the official doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads)) so use at your own risk as future updates might break it. 
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileid/?key=yourapikey&alt=media

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Google uses the following URL format for the final download link:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=s5vl&id=XXX
```

Notice the confirm parameter which seems to change every time you go to the original link. Maybe it's a short lived token or cookie matching or something?

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2423534)

> You can download these files to your computer in the following
>   formats:
>
> ```
> For documents: HTML, RTF, Word, Open Office, PDF, Text file.
> For spreadsheets: CSV, HTML, ODS, PDF, XLS, TXT (only for a single sheet)
> For presentations: PDF, PPTX, TXT
> For drawings: PNG, JPEG, SVG, PDF
> ```
>
> Download a file to your computer from Google Drive
>
> ```
> Click the checkbox(es) next to the item(s) that you'd like to download.
> Expand the More drop-down menu, and select Download...
> Select a file format to which you'd like convert and download your item, such as Microsoft Word. If you select multiple items, they'll be
> ```
>
> compressed into a .zip file
>       Click Download.
>
> You can also download a file when you're viewing the file. Go to the
>   File menu, point your mouse to Download as, and select a file format.

If total file is above 2GB I don't think you'll be able to download without breaking into batches.

Comment: alas, it's a binary file :( neither of the above.

Answer (score 0):

I simply create a [javascript](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SmartManoj/GDrive/master/BypassGDriveVirusScan.js) so that it automatically capture the link and download and close the tab  with the help of [tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Bypass Google drive virus scan
// @namespace    SmartManoj
// @version      0.1
// @description  Quickly get the download link
// @author       SmartManoj
// @match        https://drive.google.com/uc?id=*&export=download*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function demo() {
    await sleep(5000);
    window.close();
}

(function() {
    location.replace(document.getElementById("uc-download-link").href);
    demo();
})();
```