# IMPORTDATA Google Sheet CSV on Google Drive

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, csv, importdata

So I'm starting to really get into utilizing Google Drive to streamline my many personal projects.  One of the things I'd love to do is figure out how to download CSV files onto my Google Drive, and have Google Sheets automatically do an `=IMPORTDATA` on any new `.csv` files in a specific directory.

I've come across a number of problems trying to figure this out, but the biggest issue is that putting any kind of file on the Google Drive doesn't give you a link to the file itself, but rather something like such:

```
https://drive.google.com/a/xxxx/file/x/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/view?usp=sharing
```

`=IMPORTDATA` doesn't recognize this as a `.csv` file.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: All answers here are deprecated. I have a more recent solution but I need more reputation to post an anwser.

Answer (score 5):

Generating a direct download link, as described [in this article](http://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/) seems to work fine with the `=IMPORTDATA` function.

To summarize, you take the `SITE_ID` string from the sharing link you have:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/FILE_ID/edit?usp=sharing
```

Using this, you can generate the direct download link for use with the `=IMPORTDATA` function:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me a 403 Google error

Comment: A HTTP 403 error indicates that the user isn't allowed access to the requested resource. Can you access the download URL used directly from your browser? Have sharing permissions on the document changed?

Answer (score 1):

1. The file should be shared to anyone or to anyone with the link
2. If the file is "small enough" the URL to be used should have the form

   ```
   https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID
   ```
3. If the file is big it could not be imported by using IMPORTDATA as Google Drive big files return a warning

References

[Google Drive direct download for big files](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/43386/88163)