# How to create direct link to Google Drive File & Folder?

Tags: google-drive

How to create Direct link to Google Drive File or Folder. So that instead of opening in preview window, the file should be downloaded directly. Please Help!

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Related https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/30654/88163

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Google Drive, how can you link directly to "Download" a zip file and not view the contents?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30654/in-google-drive-how-can-you-link-directly-to-download-a-zip-file-and-not-view)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Creating direct links to google drive file is very using the File Sharing options.
Google Drive itself gives you a option to create shared option but like you said they open in a preview window instead of downloading it directly.

Just Follow these steps:-

1. Open **Google drive** & Select the desired file to create direct link.
2. Now Right Click on it & Select **Share**.
3. Now your shared URL will be generated. So Click on **Get Link**.
4. Now the main step to convert the shared Url to [Direct Download link](https://www.buildsometech.com/2018/12/google-drive-direct-download-link.html).
5. For this you can use the **Link Generator** mentioned in the above link.

Thanks. Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm downvoting this answer because it doesn't give the answer. It just links to a website that gives the answer. I'm upvoting Ian Hyzy's answer, because he gives the actual information we're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following URL format to download a file directly:

`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=[YOUR FILE ID]`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, I am getting a 404 when trying to download an excel file.

Comment: @FilipeCorreia I just tried it with a .jpg in my account and it worked but it failed with a sheets file. For Office/Google file types I think you have to specify additional parameters; I tried with `?format=xlsx` as well but it still failed, I'm not sure what else it wants.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this
https://pixelplayz1887.github.io/Google-Drive-Direct-Link-Generator/
you can generate direct link for files above 100 MB with this

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/151014)